# How Can I Copy & Paste The Comments As Same Format - Xcode

Tags: xcode4.5, copy-paste

I would like to copy and paste my class description comments (which is aligned using keyboard tab button) to another class.

I have used cmd+c and cmd+v buttons to do the above.However the comment/text alignment seems to be different format.

**Original comments copied**
[image]

**Comments shown after pasted**
[image]

So how can I copy and paste the comments as same format in Xcode

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit -> Paste and Preserve Formatting

[image]